# Python2.7 import: recognises directory but not modules within

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-module, pythonpath

I'm trying to import the module `my_app/common/model/Model.py` into the file `/my_app/common/database/db_update.py`. My `PYTHONPATH` points to `app/common/`. However, when I try to do so, I get the error message:

```
  File "/home/me/my_app/common/database/db_update.py", line 26, in <module>
    import model.Model
ImportError: No module named Model
```

A simplified representation of my file structure is as follows:

```
common/
├── customlogger
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── logger.py
│   └── logger.pyc
├── database
│   ├── DBSetup.py
│   ├── DBSetup.pyc
│   ├── db_update.py
│   ├── db_update.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── model
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── Model.py
    └── Model.pyc
```

The head of the `db_update.py` file contains the following imports (amongst others) in this order:

```
import customlogger.logger
import database.DBSetup
import model.Model
```

Some information that may be useful:

- I have tried importing other modules from the `model/` directory. These are also not recognised and result in the same error (with the respective module's name instead).
- I am running a bash script to do this, from a directory adjacent to `common/` - call it `my_app/src/`.
- All my `__init__.py` files are empty.
- I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

It seems to me that python recognises the `model/` directory (else, the error message would read `ImportError: No module named model.Model`), but seems to think that it doesn't contains any modules despite the presence of the `__init__.py` file. Is this the case? And if so, why does this happen exclusively in the `model/` directory and not the `database/` nor the `customlogger/` directories? Finally, how can I fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be you have a directory called model in the default python path? Did you provide the full path variable output here?

Comment: What do you get if you import just `model`? While at it you could try `from model import Model`. P.S. to test if name "model" is a problem, try renaming it to `model2`

Comment: I tried importing `model` to no avail. Indeed, it turned out that changing the name from `model` to `model2` fixed the problem. Thanks to the both of you.